# What does the phrase "going well in the soft" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does anyone know what does this phrase mean: "Piper going well in the soft, lads. Down to fourth". I think it was about bets. The phrase was from a tv series "Peaky Blinders".

Comment: 'In the soft' means 'in the soft conditions at the racecourse' (often the case in rainy Britain). Some horses prefer soft conditions, others firm.  'Going well' means 'running a good race', so I'd expect 'up to fourth' (ie just having moved up to fourth place) rather than 'down to fourth'. 'Piper' is a racehorse (the conditions aren't usually mentioned in greyhound racing).

Comment: It's even called the [**going**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/going) (meaning 2). "What's the going like today?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it refers to how soft the ground is at the racecourse. Some horses like a hard track, others prefer soft - and are often referred to as 'mudlarks'.